# An algorithm to find the special person

Tags: algorithms

There is a party in a class with $n$ students. One of the students called Robert is holding this party. There is two-way friendship relation between some of the students. Each student can attend the party iff one of these conditions hold:

1. He is Robert
2. He is a friend of someone who attends the party

Robert hates Susan. So he wants to find a way so that Susan can't come to the party. The friendship graph of the students is such that the shortest path between Robert and Susan has more than $n/2$ edges.

a) Prove that some student exists that if he doesn't come, then Susan can't come to the party.  (Robert always attends, so you cannot select Robert for this.)

b) Provide an algorithm of $O(m+n)$ to find this student. ($m$ is the number of edges and $n$ is the number of students)

I can find the paths between Robert and Susan with BFS. The problem is these two questions written above.

Answer (score 3):

<s>In this case, the trivial solution works.

If Robert doesn't attend the party, no one attends the party. So there exists someone who, if they don't come to the party, Susan can't come to the party.


If the trivial solution isn't allowed, lets examine the case where n=4. There are 4 students: Robert, nameless student 1, nameless student 2, and Susan. Let Robert be friends with both unnamed students, and Susan be friends with both nameless students. There must be some solution for this setup. But if we remove either nameless student, we've achieved nothing. Removing Susan doesn't seem to be an option from the wording of part a. So, unless the trivial solution of removing Robert is allowed, this case has no solution. I.E. the trivial solution must be allowed, and is a general solution.</s>

Edited in response to a change in the question.
If there is one person who can choose not to attend, and cause Susan to not be able to attend, then that person is on every path from Robert to Susan. 
If we assume no such person exists, then that means there are at least two paths from Robert to Susan, which share no intermediate people. Because the shortest path from Robert to Susan has length greater than n/2, that means the sum of the length of both paths is at least n+2, and a path of length l contains l+1 verticies, so there are at least n/2+2 people in both paths, or n+4 people in both paths.
 The beginning and end of both paths are the same, so the n-2 nameless people somehow make up two paths, both of which must contain at least n/2+1 of the nameless people. By the pigeonhole principle, no such two paths exist.